# Python/Pygame 2.7 Text to image conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite, game-engine

I am writing a program that reads from an external file (level.lev) and converts the x's and o's in that file into red and green squares accordingly into a pygame window. The code works for detecting how many characters are in the text file and draws that many squares but I have no clue how to differentiate between x's and o's as seperate variables. Only the code that takes care of this is below.

```
level_file = open("level.lev")

read_num = 0

for word in level_file:
    for ch in word:
        read_num+=1

while(True):
    while read_num > 0:
        screen.blit(x_spr,(((64*read_num)-64),0))
        read_num-=1
```

Comment: If an answer to your questions solves your issue, please accept it. Would be helpful to others as well as save time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

Since you are interested in reading single characters, you can reduce the two for loops into one:

```
characters = level_file.read()
for ch in characters:
```

Instead of bliting the x after reading the file, it is better to construct a list of sprites. It can be done like this:

```
sprites = []    
characters = level_file.read()
for x in range(len(characters),0,-1):
    pos = (((64*x)-64),0))
    sprites.append((some_sprite,pos))
```

Then you can blit them accordingly.

```
for sprite in sprites:
    screen.blit(sprite[0],sprite[1])
```

During sprite list creation, you can look at what char contains, and add the corresponding object. Something along these lines:

```
for x in range(len(characters)-1,-1,-1):
    pos = (((64*x)-64),0))
    if characters[x] == 'X':
        sprites.append((x_spr,pos))
    else:
        sprites.append((o_spr,pos))
```